# how to create multiple clients in one server?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, client-server

how create multiple clients with is code

program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Server.ServerCode(5656);
    } 
}
```

Client.cs

```
class Client
{
    public static void ClientCode()
    {
            //SOCKET CONNECTION

            //int Port = (int)port;
            Console.WriteLine("......................CLIENT.........................");

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.01", 5656);
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(clientStream);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(clientStream);
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
                //CLOSING SOCKET
                clientStream.Close();
                client.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
```

my server code:

sereve.cs

```
class Server
{
    public static void ServerCode(object port)

    {

        //SOCKET CONNECTION

        int Port = (int)port;
        Console.WriteLine("................SERVER RUNNING......................");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), Port);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient serverSite = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            if (serverSite.Connected)
            {
                Thread c = new Thread((fileTransfer));
                c.Start(serverSite);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void fileTransfer(object clients)
    {


            Console.WriteLine("new client");*/
            TcpClient server = listener.AcceptTcpClient();//(TcpClient)clients;
            NetworkStream serverStream = server.GetStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(serverStream);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(serverStream);
            sw.AutoFlush = true;



            //CHECKING USERNAME AND PASSWORD
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Client... ");
            string fromClient_u = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Username: " + fromClient_u);
            string fromClient_p = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Password: *******");
            if (fromClient_u == "Client1" && fromClient_p == "123456")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\nClient has Successfully Loged In. ");
                sw.WriteLine("Connection Complete...  ");                       //msg1
                sw.WriteLine("Successfully Connected to the Server.");          //msg2
                sw.WriteLine("Enter Some Informations for File Transfer...");   //msg3

            }
            //CLOSING SOCKET
            serverStream.Close();
            server.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();

    }   

}
```

its not working. I want the first thread to work and end, then the 2nd thread to start. but this code generates all the three threat at once. my point is , multiple client will be created by this code and they will wait. when the 1st client is done working with the server then the 2nd client will get server connection.

Comment: Please expand "on its not working". What error's do you see? When and doing what?

Comment: What is the meaning of `lock (obje)`?

Comment: there is no error.but when the whole code runs all the thread works at once. I want one thread to access the server one at a time. @ImmortalBlue

Comment: I don't know the meaning of  lock (obje) exactly ... I saw many codes on internet like this... but it is not locking any client I guess. @HamletHakobyan

Comment: `lock()` is used to locking a code path in a multi threaded app to avoid more than one thread from modifying the same values. It makes the calling threads waits until released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as it may sound, if you want to lock the process until the client ends and then starts the next one, just loop and call it explicitly:

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    Client.ClientCode();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without also providing your server code it's hard to know if problems don't exist there as well. If it helps to have a comparison checkout this article on how to [create a quick client and server application](http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/). The example also allows any number of clients, although they have to be started as independent processes, not threads.

To only run one client at a time, you could try changing your starting code as follows:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        t[i].Start();
        t[i].Join();
    }
```

Comment: I want to add my server code now . how do I add it. the code is too large for the comment box.

Comment: @Giliweed - You should be able to edit your original post and add it there.

Comment: @Giliweed - My pleasure. Which solution did you get working in the end?

Comment: I see no point of using threading if he doesn't want to process anything asynchronously.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders - Given people don't generally use multitasking unless there is cause I assumed that was the case here, hence my answer. If there is indeed no good reason then definitely get rid of the threads.

Comment: excuse me, I'm a girl. :) @Mt.Schneiders ....

Comment: my teacher told me to do this code using multitheading that's why I used threading. Now I understand it was a trick. My teacher wanted me to find out that threading is not needed at all.and I did thanks to you guys. @MarcF

Comment: both solution is working good! .... In the end I choose not to use thread (cause there is no need). but I learned a lot today. thanks to you both. @MarcF

Comment: Sorry, @ Giliweed :). That's a weird trick actually. Are you sure that is the behavior he wanted? Because it doesn't really teach you how to use multitheading. In fact, i'm not sure what this trick actually teaches you.